TraCI server "SUMO 1.21.0" reports API version 21, which is unsupported
I'm trying to simulate a c-v2x scenario in Omnet++ 6.0.3, Veins 5.2, Inet 4.5 and Simu5G. My SUMO version, as in the title, is in 1.21.0.
After building my project and running the Scenario with sumo-gui server open, it returns me an error:

<!> TraCI server "SUMO 1.21.0" reports API version 21, which is unsupported. We recommend using the version of sumo-launchd that ships with Veins. -- in module (veins::TraCIScenarioManagerLaunchd) Cv2xSimulation.manager (id=6), at t=0s, event #2

What can I do to revert this? Do I need to downgrade my SUMO version or there is other possibility? If I need to downgrade, what version should I use for Veins 5.2?
